# How to make routing in Ext 4.2.1

Tags: extjs, routes

Hello i am want set up routing in my project, on  Ext 4.2.1. I am download Routing master. What next? give me resource about routing  in extjs, thanks

Comment: Look at the official documentation 'Ext.History'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an official example of History implementation in Ext 4.2 - 
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/history/history.html#main-tabs:tab3